# How to expose only a few inherited CRUD API controller methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, crud

To speed up development in a small team (and also to enforce consistent REST-ish API), I have created a generic base API controller and also a related generic business service base class that has typical CRUD methods for domain root entities:

- create
- get by key
- update
- delete
- get a page of records (with a simple query expression and pagination that gets automatically parsed into a Linq expression
- get a simple list with all records (id-name pair projections for many cases when that's all you need, e.g. for a dropdown list).

It worked pretty well for most cases. We also had similar architecture on Angular side with some code generation scripts and we could spit out hundreds of forms for a small ERP-like system in a short time.

However, we had quite a few entities that did not need all those CRUD methods. Our Swagger definitions were polluted with methods that should not actually be available and we had to override them and add ignore attributes and throw `NotImplementedException` as needed.

**Is there any clean solution to this CRUD inheritance mess?** Is it possible to somehow specify to ASP.NET "hey, for this controller I want to generate routes only for these specific CRUD base methods and ignore all the other ones"? Of course, I would still want to be able to add non-CRUD custom routes and methods to controllers, as usual; so I don't need fully dynamic runtime-generated controllers but only their methods.

*In an ideal world, .net should have traits like PHP, so that I could add e.g. "GetByIdTrait" etc...*

Comment: Use composition over inheritance

Comment: Liskov principle: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual_articles/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design#liskov-substitution-principle

Comment: @DanielA.White  yep, I was thinking along these lines but I have no idea how to make it work with ASP.NET controllers - how to bring in only a few CRUD methods I need without having to duplicate those methods in controllers.

Comment: @GHDevOps  I wish there was a way to do multiple inherit from abstract classes like GetByIdMethodController, GetListMethodController etc...

Comment: controllers are really not well suited anymore consider using endpoints.

Comment: SOLID would say you should have individual `ICreate`, `IDelete`, and so on interfaces that get implemented by the components that actually need them.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: Probably not a good idea.  ASP.NET and EF already have idioms for this sort of thing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, agreed but instead of debating that one more time, sometimes you just give straight advice for the problem at hand.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank you, this actually might be a good solution to get rid of CRUD controllers. I definitely will have to look into the endpoints feature.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: Is your advice to implement those interfaces or to avoid them?

Comment: @RobertHarvey for this situation, my general advice would be to avoid them but to deal with the issue at hand, I would advice it would be *a way* to prevent the controllers from being forced to depend on interfaces it doesn't need to implement.